# Untiy , how to disable log message from google play game service plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

These log message are so annoying. It show every time i hit play button on Unity.

[image]

How to disable it?

Comment: if you double click on the log does it take you to the source file where a debug.log is called? if so just comment it out/delete it. If it doesn't and its tucked away in some dll then i don't think you can do a whole lot about it

Comment: @remy_rm i have tried double on it. it didn't go anywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid its packed into a .dll then, which you cannot edit unless you have the unpacked source code.. I don't think there is a way to stop these logs from showing up then. Someone may correct me on this.

Comment: @remy_rm thank you.

Comment: @remy_rm Nope. There is a way to do so

Comment: @Programmer As i said i wasn't sure and may be corrected. If there's a way i'd love to know of it.

Comment: @remy_rm Could you please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Tkaewkunha I'm not sure of a way how to do it since it is most likely build into a .dll file. maybe @Programmer can clarify what his way would be, as he said it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Solution from: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2104#issuecomment-472257518

try Assets>PlayServiceResolver>version handler>settings and uncheck the verbose logging.

The logs that remained I could remove by deleting Debug.Log from the plugin code.